# drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment: is deprecated iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

My code is displaying this below warning' is deprecated in iOS 7

```
[@"•" drawInRect: r
                withFont: f2
           lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByCharWrapping
               alignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

Is there any other method that may i use?

Answer (score 1):

From the Xcode warning you're looking at:

> Use `-drawInRect:withAttributes:`.